# populate listView from another listView

Tags: android-studio

i want to populate a listView from the first listView that show all applications installed on the device, the second listView is on the second activity called "Blocked app" , my point is when i click on first  listView items , the item should going to the second listView "Blocked App" for making an password interface thank uu and sorry for my english:

here is my MainActivity.Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PackageManager packageManager=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final ListView userInstalledApps=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.installed_apps_list);

    packageManager=getPackageManager();

    final List<AppList>installedApp=getInstalledApps();
    final AppAdapter installedAppAdapter=new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this,installedApp);
    userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);



    userInstalledApps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivlock)).setImageResource(R.drawable.unlocked);



            // i shouuld write something here



        }
    });
}



private List<AppList> getInstalledApps()
{
    List<AppList> resList=new ArrayList<AppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < packs.size() ; i++)
    {

        PackageInfo pi= packs.get(i);


        if ((isSystemPackage(pi)== false))
        {
            String appName=pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable dIcon=pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            resList.add(new AppList(appName,dIcon));
        }

    }
    return resList;
}

private  boolean  isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo)
{
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) !=0) ? true : false;
}


public class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<AppList> listExtStorage;


    public AppAdapter(Context context,List<AppList> customListView)

    {
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listExtStorage=customListView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return listExtStorage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            listViewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list,parent, false);
            listViewHolder.AppNameInList=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_name_in_list);
            listViewHolder.AppIconInList=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.apps_icon);

            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        }

        else
        {
            listViewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        listViewHolder.AppNameInList.setText(listExtStorage.get(position).getName());
        listViewHolder.AppIconInList.setImageDrawable(listExtStorage.get(position).getIcon());

        return convertView;
    }
}
static class ViewHolder

{
    TextView AppNameInList;
    ImageView AppIconInList;
}



public class AppList
{
    private String name;
    Drawable icon;


    public AppList(String name, Drawable icon)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.icon=icon;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon()
    {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Any code of yours?

Comment: this is the code of first MainActivity.Java:

Comment: plz , i need help , any help from uu can be very usefull ,thanks a lot